# why does my button not work for php and javascript, while my other buttons work?

Tags: javascript, button

My button does not work for my website I am developing right now, I did the exact same thing for my other buttons. But just on that specific page my buttons won't work.

```
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="bestelling.css" />

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">

</head>

<script>

    function Aanvaarden()
    {
        window.location.assign=("Welcome.php")
    }

    function Annuleren()
    {
        window.location.assign=("Annuleren.php")
    }

</script>

<br>

<input class="MyButton" type="button" value="Aanvaarden" onclick="Aanvaarden()" />
<input class="MyButton" type="button" value="Annuleren" onclick="Annuleren()" />
```

this is my code behind my buttons, what do I need to do?

Comment: Try without equal `window.location.assign("Annuleren.php");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the equal to sign after "assign". Your code should now work with the revision below.

```
    function Aanvaarden()
    {
        window.location.assign("Welcome.php")
    }

    function Annuleren()
    {
        window.location.assign("Annuleren.php")
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

`window.location.assign` is a **function**.

Assigning a string to it (with `=`) will just remove the function and replace it with a string.

It will have no visible effect unless some other code tries to call `assign`, at which point it will throw an error because it isn't a function.

To use it, you should call the function and pass an argument:

```
window.location.assign("Annuleren.php")
```

That said, a regular link instead of a button with some JavaScript would almost certainly be a better, easier, more accessible solution.

Comment: thanks a lot! but can you explain why it works on my other pages with a "="?

Comment: @MaartenGregoor — It doesn't, but I can't see what you are doing on those pages which would lead you to think that.